# Laravel string validation to allow empty strings

Tags: php, laravel, validation

In Laravel 5.7 I am using form request validation:

```
public function rules() 
{
    return [
        'age' => 'integer',
        'title' => 'string|max:50'
    ];
}
```

If I submit a request to my API with this payload:

```
{
  "age": 24,
  "title": ""
}
```

Laravel returns the error:

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "title": [
            "The title must be a string."
        ]
    }
}
```

I would expect it to pass the validation, since the title is a string, albeit an empty one. How should the validation be formulated to allow empty strings?

Comment: Try adding the `present` or `required` validator as well

Comment: @ka_lin Present and required do not describe this property, which doesn't need to be present and is not required.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try to see if `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware is active then it would explain this behavior, see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields)

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. I'm not confident removing that middleware in case it's used elsewhere. But it explains the behaviour.

Answer (score 58):

You would need `nullable` to allow an empty string

```
public function rules() 
{
    return [
        'age' => 'integer',
        'title' => 'nullable|string|max:50'
    ];
}
```

Comment: nullable - The field under validation may be null. This is particularly useful when validating primitive such as strings and integers that can contain null values.

Comment: This doesn't allow an empty string, this simply ignores an empty string, treating it as `null`. What if we want to overwrite the existing `title` field with an empty string?

Comment: @GluePear if you wanted to do that you would also need to disable `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class` from your middleware. That middleware will automatically convert empty strings to null. From a database normalisation point of view, it would be better to have `null` as the value rather than an empty string anyway.

Comment: I confirm this does work. If you leave that specific field empty, `nullable` makes it pass being empty. [Here are the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields).

Comment: Any solution in case you have $request->file('image')? Both nullable and sometimes doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

there is `present` rule in that check present of a key but let it to be empty.

> #present
>
> present
> The field under validation must be present in the input data but can be empty.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-present

Answer (score 0):

I will try

```php
public function rules() 
{
    return [
        'age' => 'integer',
        'title' => 'string|sometimes'
    ];
}
```

This will only validate title when it is present.

Comment: Doesn't answer the problem when you want it to always be present, though allowed to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid** touching Middleware settings.

Instead Use Laravel build in function to manipulate data before validation runs.

Inside Validation class

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        if($this->title == null )
            $this->merge(['title'=>'']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does not fix the issue when you have this rule:

```php
return [
  "title" => "sometimes|string",
];
```

In this case, you need to specifiy the string is actually "nullable" (even if the `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull`  middleware is active, tested on Laravel 8.77.1)

So this one will allow to pass an empty string on the "title" key:

```php
return [
  "title" => "sometimes|string|nullable",
];
```